# Join Pyspark DataFrame with sql like partition by condition

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark-sql

How to join two Pyspark DataFrames on sql like partition by condition?
I actually need to join two data frames such that for each group (based on a column variable), I outer join with other table.

For instance I have following two data frames:

df1:

[image]

df2:

[image]

Required output is something like:

[image]

I have tried to use `Window` operator of Pyspark but couldn't as it can not be used for join over a window.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to say, there is a logic for any kind of join missing as per your output expectation.

However, take a look at the `cross join,` which can be closely related to your expectation,.

```
>>> df_1.crossJoin(df_2).withColumn("match",  when((df_1.batch==df_2.batch) & (df_1.subject==df_2.subject) , "Yes").otherwise("No")).show()
+-------+-----+---------+-----+---------+-----+
|exam_id|batch|  subject|batch|  subject|match|
+-------+-----+---------+-----+---------+-----+
|      1|   X1|    maths|   X1|    maths|  Yes|
|      1|   X1|    maths|   X1|  english|   No|
|      1|   X1|    maths|   X1|chemistry|   No|
|      1|   X1|  english|   X1|    maths|   No|
|      1|   X1|  english|   X1|  english|  Yes|
|      1|   X1|  english|   X1|chemistry|   No|
|      2|   X1|chemistry|   X1|    maths|   No|
|      2|   X1|chemistry|   X1|  english|   No|
|      2|   X1|chemistry|   X1|chemistry|  Yes|
+-------+-----+---------+-----+---------+-----+
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, however expected output is different.
Actually, for every unique exam id, an outer join is required. Here, in final output for exam_id 1, we have 6 rows, but actually, only 3 (number of rows in df2) are expected.
Any suggestions?